# Is "just in case" the same as "if and only if"?

Tags: terminology

I am reading "[Causal Models](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causal-models/)" by Christopher Hitchcock. He frequently uses the phrase "just in case"--is this the same as "if and only if"?

---

Examples:

[image]

Another example outside the context of definitions:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of of "just in case" in a sentence?

Comment: Yes, it appears so.

Comment: This seems to be an informal way to give definitions. Many authors, intending informal phrasing, might begin your first example as "$A$ and $B$ are said to be probabilistically independent (with respect to P) when_______." For the final word "when," often "if" is written instead.

Answer (score 0):

US philosophers (inc logicians) and some US mathematicians use it to mean 'if, and only if.' According to Language Log (2006), the phrase is not thus used in the UK. [http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/003470.html](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/003470.html)